# Is there any way the openldap allows us to set a DSCP (QOS(IP_TOS) in IP layer) values?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, openldap

My application uses the openldap stack to send the request to LDAP server, I want to set the DSCP (IP_TOS) values is there any way to do this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use setsockopt on the LDAP sockets:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int tos = IPTOS_LOWDELAY;

if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TOS, (char *) &tos, sizeof(tos)) < 0 ) {
       printf("Failed setting TOS on socket");
       abort(); 
}
```

Comment: yeah I know this whic code I need to modify to that in openldap that is my question.